# Translate LEFT JOIN UNNEST in Presto/Trino to Hive

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql, presto, trino

Was wondering what the equivalent of the below in Presto/Trino is

```
LEFT JOIN UNNEST(colname) as t(renamedcol) on true
```

On Hive

I know CROSS JOIN UNNEST translates to LATERAL VIEW EXPLODE but I can't figure out the syntax for LEFT JOIN UNNEST for whatever reason

Answer (score 0):

For those wondering, this is equivalent to

```
LATERAL VIEW OUTER explode()
```